# How to get the unit test method name at runtime from within the unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automated-tests, teamcity

How to get the unit test name from the within unit test?

I have the below method inside a BaseTestFixture Class:

```
public string GetCallerMethodName()
{
    var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    StackFrame stackFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(1);
    MethodBase methodBase = stackFrame.GetMethod();
    return methodBase.Name;
}
```

My Test Fixture class inherits from the base one:

```
[TestFixture]
public class WhenRegisteringUser : BaseTestFixture
{
}
```

and I have the below system test:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldRegisterThenVerifyEmailThenSignInSuccessfully_WithValidUsersAndSites()
{
    string testMethodName = this.GetCallerMethodName();
    //
}
```

When I run this from within the Visual Studio, it returns my test method name as expected.

When this runs by TeamCity, instead `_InvokeMethodFast()` is returned which seems to be a method that TeamCity generates at runtime for its own use.

So how could I get the test method name at runtime?

Comment: Is it compiled in release mode even when launched from VS?

Comment: Do you get the assembly info for each method called in the stack? Maybe you could walk up the stack looking for your test assembly.

Comment: A stacktrace would help, to see if the actual method name is listed farther up the call stack.

Comment: You have more than 60 questions without an accepted. Do find that respectful to the people helping you?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are using **NUnit 2.5.7 / 2.6** you can use the [TestContext class](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testContext&r=2.6):

```
[Test]
public void ShouldRegisterThenVerifyEmailThenSignInSuccessfully()
{
    string testMethodName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
}
```

Comment: MSTest also exposes this info in its TestContext as well

Comment: It now runs fine from TeamCity but when I run it locally from within Visual Studio, it throws an exception that an object is not initialized. So how to make it work from within Visual studio?

Comment: @William Wich test runner are you using?

Comment: This answer still works in 2022 with NUnit 3.13.

Answer (score 23):

When using Visual Studio to run your tests if you add a [TestContext property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms404699(v=vs.90).aspx) in your test class you can get this information easily.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void setup()
    {
        logger.Info(" SETUP " + TestContext.TestName);
        // .... //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are not using NUnit you can loop over the stack and find the test method:

```
foreach(var stackFrame in stackTrace.GetFrames()) {
  MethodBase methodBase = stackFrame.GetMethod();
  Object[] attributes = methodBase.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false);
  if (attributes.Length >= 1) {
    return methodBase.Name;
  } 
}
return "Not called from a test method";
```

Comment: Do you know if this only works on MSTest? Or it will work on both NUnit and MSTest?

Comment: You would need to change the annotation to be the right annotation for the test framework. However as the accepted answer points out, NUnit has a TestContext which is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was asking because I am trying to build a FW and I dont want to restrict myself to NUnit or MSTest. So I think what I will do is to loop the stack from the bottom to the top until I find a method which it namespace is not from Microsoft or System. I have tried this and I got good results with MSTest and calling the FW from a command line program (I got the main method).

Comment: please note that in Release builds this sometimes does not work - the test method may be inlined and you will not be able to see the TestAttribute

Comment: Here's a LINQ one-liner `string testName = new StackTrace().GetFrames()?.Select(stackFrame => stackFrame.GetMethod()).FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false).Any())?.Name ?? "Not called from a test method";`

Answer (score 7):

Thanks guys; I used a combined approach so it now works in all environments:

```
public string GetTestMethodName()
{
    try
    {
        // for when it runs via TeamCity
        return TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
    }
    catch
    {
        // for when it runs via Visual Studio locally
        var stackTrace = new StackTrace(); 
        foreach (var stackFrame in stackTrace.GetFrames())
        {
            MethodBase methodBase = stackFrame.GetMethod();
            Object[] attributes = methodBase.GetCustomAttributes(
                                      typeof(TestAttribute), false); 
            if (attributes.Length >= 1)
            {
                return methodBase.Name;
            }
        }
        return "Not called from a test method";  
    }
}
```

Comment: please note that in Release builds this sometimes does not work - the test method may be inlined and you will not be able to see the TestAttribute

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Nunit or any other third party tool. you will not get **TestAttribute**.

So you can do this to get Test Method name.
Use **TestMethodAttribute** insted of **TestAttribute**.

```
    public string GetTestMethodName()
    {
            // for when it runs via Visual Studio locally
            var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
            foreach (var stackFrame in stackTrace.GetFrames())
            {
                MethodBase methodBase = stackFrame.GetMethod();
                Object[] attributes = methodBase.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMethodAttribute), false);
                if (attributes.Length >= 1)
                {
                    return methodBase.Name;
                }
            }
            return "Not called from a test method";
    }
```

Comment: Here it is as a LINQ one-liner: Here's a LINQ one-liner `public string GetTestMethodName() => new StackTrace().GetFrames()?.Select(stackFrame => stackFrame.GetMethod()).FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMethodAttribute), false).Any())?.Name ?? "Not called from a test method";`