# Get status and name of unit test inside of TestCleanup

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

I'm currently using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting Attribute `<TestCleanup()>` in a VB.Net project.
Because some of my tests can leave the world a bit messy (after a fail that is) I need to find out wether the test for which a particular cleanup is running failed or not. Also the actual name of the "current" test (the one I'm cleaning up for) would be helpfull.

Is there a way to access this information?

Comment: Not sure in VB. In C# there's the [CallerMemberName] arg which I add to a util function and return back. See if this is relevant maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666562/how-to-get-the-unit-test-method-name-at-runtime-from-within-the-unit-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't already have one, then you need to add a TestContext property to your class. This will be populated by the test runner and then you can check it in your cleanup.

The bits you are interested in are `TestContext.TestName` for the name of the test currently being executed and `TestContext.UnitTestOutcome` for the success state of the test.

Something like this:

```
Public Property TestContext As TestContext

<TestCleanup> Public Sub Cleanup()
    If (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome = UnitTestOutcome.Passed And
        TestContext.TestName = "TestMethod1") Then
        'Do something
    Else
        'Do something else
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Tnx a million! will try this!

Comment: Thank you. I never took the time to answer and say thanks. Sorry for that. It works  using test context.
P.S.: Sorry can't upvote as I don't have the necessary rep.